# How do I get first, second or last Tuesday (or any day of the week) of a given month

Tags: vb.net

I was looking for a function in VB.net that returns the date of the specified weekday of a given week in a month. Something similar to Outlook appointments.

for example:
First Monday of the month, 
Second Thursday of the month or
Last Saturday of the month

I searched but couldn't find anything versatile enough to all the options. So I created my own and would like to share it.

Comment: it does not appear that you provided an answer. If you're going to answer your own question, I have voted to re-open it. It will need a few more votes to re-open.

Comment: The problem was that you posted the code in the question. Please provide the code as an answer to your question instead.

Comment: David Zemens: I had provided the answer as part of the question, but that was confusing so I edited the question and deleted the code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
Public Function GetDate()

    Dim dt As Date = Today

    Dim FirstWeek As Integer = 1
    Dim SecondWeek As Integer = 2
    Dim ThirdWeek As Integer = 3
    Dim FourthWeek As Integer = 4
    Dim LastWeek As Integer = 5

    MsgBox(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(dt, DayOfWeek.Monday, LastWeek).ToString)

End Function

Public Function GetNthDayOfNthWeek(ByVal dt As Date, ByVal DayofWeek As Integer, ByVal WhichWeek As Integer) As Date
    'specify which day of which week of a month and this function will get the date
    'this function uses the month and year of the date provided

    'get first day of the given date
    Dim dtFirst As Date = DateSerial(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1)

    'get first DayOfWeek of the month
    Dim dtRet As Date = dtFirst.AddDays(6 - dtFirst.AddDays(-(DayofWeek + 1)).DayOfWeek)

    'get which week
    dtRet = dtRet.AddDays((WhichWeek - 1) * 7)

    'if day is past end of month then adjust backwards a week
    If dtRet >= dtFirst.AddMonths(1) Then
        dtRet = dtRet.AddDays(-7)
    End If

    'return
    Return dtRet

End Function
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function GetLastDayOfMonth(ByVal iMonth As Integer, ByVal iYear As Integer) As Integer
    Dim LastDate = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth + 1, 0)
    GetLastDayOfMonth = LastDate.Day

    Return GetLastDayOfMonth
End Function

Private Function GetWeekNumberOfMonth(ByVal Dt As Date) As Integer
        Dim LastDate = New DateTime(Dt.Year, Dt.Month, GetLastDayOfMonth(Dt.Month, Dt.Year), Dt.Hour, Dt.Minute, Dt.Second, Dt.Kind)
        Dim weekNumber As Integer = Math.Ceiling(Dt.Day / 7)
        If weekNumber = 4 Then
            Dim dateDiff = CInt((LastDate - Dt).TotalDays)
            If dateDiff < 7 Then weekNumber = 5
        End If

        Return weekNumber
    End Function
```

Comment: Your code is not complete without the `GetLastDayOfMonth` function.