# How to know today is which Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. (in number) of this month?

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, dayofweek

My question is:

Today's Day and Date are: Wednesday, June 8, 2016. I want to know today is which Wednesday of the current Month (like 2nd Wednesday). How I can do this using VB .NET?

I have tried the solution provided in:

[How do I get first, second or last Tuesday (or any day of the week) of a given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520008/how-do-i-get-first-second-or-last-tuesday-or-any-day-of-the-week-of-a-given-m)

This solution accepts "Name of the Day" and "Week Number of the Day" and provides the output as the Date. I want the results differently as I should input the Date and the result should be the "Day Number of the Day" and "Current Day Name", like "Today is 2nd Wednesday".

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You know how to get the weekday? Ok, then, make an integer division  on the day of the month and add 1 to the result: on the 8th of june you will get 1, and this is correct because this week wednesday is the second wednesday of june.

Comment: Show what you've tried. Surely it is just counting the number of Wednesdays in that month and return the ordinal position of yours?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Yes, `Math.Floor(Weekday(Date.Today) / Date.Today.Day) + 1` returns 1. How to get it as "Today is 2nd Wednesday"? Further help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim checkDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        Dim infos As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)() From {{1, "st"}, {2, "nd"}, {3, "rd"}, {4, "th"}, {5, "th"}}
        Dim dayCount As Integer = (checkDate.Day \ 7) + Convert.ToInt32((checkDate.Day Mod 7) > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Today is the {0}{1} {2} of the month", dayCount, infos(dayCount), checkDate.DayOfWeek)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Any input for shortening the length of this code:
`If(dayCount > 3, dayCount & "th", _
                         If(dayCount = 1, dayCount & "st", _
                            If(dayCount = 2, dayCount & "nd", _
                               If(dayCount = 3, dayCount & "rd", dayCount.ToString)))) & _
                   " " & Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(Date.Today))`

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way?

```
    ' 1st: You would need this:
    Dim numbers() As String = {"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"}
    For day As Integer = 1 To 30
        Dim dat As DateTime = New DateTime(2016, 6, day)

        ' 2nd: The loop was only for test purposes
        Console.WriteLine("Today is {0} {1}", numbers(day \ 7), dat.DayOfWeek.ToString())
    Next day
```